# unilateral contrast hypothesis sas

Tags: sas, mean, statistics

I do a bilateral contrast hypothesis by

```
proc means data=set alpha=0.1 t prt;
var age2;
run;
```

where age2 is equal to age2=age-1970, this procedure is for contrast mu is different to 1970 but how could I do a unilateral contrast hypothesis such as median<1970 o median>1970.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROC TTEST can easily do one-sided T tests, if that's what you're after.

```
proc ttest data=set alpha=0.1 sides=u;
var age2;
run;
```

That only can test means, though.  I'm not aware of a way to test medians one-sided.